# Repeat two elements directly in ngFor Angular

Tags: html, angular, ngfor

Angular 9

I simply need to repeat two HTML elements using *ngFor.

if I write the following code

```
<dl>
  <div *ngFor="let item of columns">
    <dt>{{ item.name }}</dt>
    <dd>{{ item.field }}</dd>
  </div>
</dl>
```

then I am receiving 3 HTML warnings

> Element 'div' cannot be nested inside element 'dl'
>   Element 'dt' cannot be nested inside element 'div'
>   Element 'dd' cannot be nested inside element 'div'

if I wrote the following code

```
<dl>
  <ng-template [ngFor]="let item of columns">
    <dt>{{ item.name }}</dt>
    <dd>{{ item.field }}</dd>
  </ng-template>
</dl>
```

I will receive an angular error in the runtime

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
>   Parser Error: Unexpected token let at column 1 in [let item of columns]

and if I wrote the following code

```
<dl *ngFor="let item of columns">
  <dt>{{ item.name }}</dt>
  <dd>{{ item.field }}</dd>
</dl>
```

then the `dl` element will be repeated and this is something that I do not want at all.

can someone give me a solution for that?

Comment: Your code is working fine. see this fiddle - https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-dirac-1rjrp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
<dl>
 <ng-container *ngFor="let item of columns">
  <dt>{{ item.name }}</dt>
  <dd>{{ item.field }}</dd>
 </ng-container>
</dl>
```

[ng-container](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#ng-container-to-the-rescue)

Comment: I do not know which answer to accept, you both helped me so much, I will accept one of the solutions and go to the other person's answers of other questions to upvote them also, I want to be fear for both of you

Comment: @HakanFıstık I answered a tiny bit faster so you should accept mine lol.

Comment: yes, you are right, I ordered the answers by the oldest and your answer popup to the top. I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't [`<ng-container>`](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#ng-container-to-the-rescue) work in this case?

> The Angular ng-container is a grouping element that doesn't interfere with styles or layout because Angular doesn't put it in the DOM.

```
<dl>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of columns">
        <dt>{{ item.name }}</dt>
        <dd>{{ item.field }}</dd>
    </ng-container>
</dl>
```

Comment: yes this is solved the problem, thank you very much

Comment: I do not know which answer to accept, you both helped me so much, I will accept one of the solutions and go to the other person's answers of other questions to upvote them also, I want to be fear for both of you